# Converting running pace from seconds/meter to minutes/mile

Tags: javascript, react-native, math, mobile, algebra

My high school algebra is failing me greatly...

I'm developing a mobile running application.  I'm using a timer counting in seconds and a GPS library that measures distance in meters.  I need to support both metric and imperial units.  I am having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to convert X number of seconds for Y number of meters to A number of minutes for B number of miles.

For example a split time of 1253 seconds with a split distance of 1754.50119 meters.

What is that in minutes per mile?

Answer (score 1):

To turn seconds into minutes, divide by `60` because there are 60 seconds in a minute.

To turn metres into miles, multiply by `1609` because there are 1609 metres in a mile.

```js
seconds = 1253;
metres = 1754.50119;

minutes = seconds / 60;
miles = metres / 1609;

console.log('Your pace was ' + minutes + ' minutes per ' + miles + ' miles');
```

The above snippet tells you the time needed for `1.09` miles, but you just want the time needed for 1 mile. So a final step is needed in the calculation.

To get from `1.09` to `1.0`, you have to multiply by `1/1.09`, or `1/miles` in terms of javascript variables.

To get the time needed for 1 mile, you therefore have to multiply `minutes` by this same number, `1/miles`.

Here is the full code:

```js
seconds = 1253;
metres = 1754.50119;

minutes = seconds / 60;
miles = metres / 1609;

console.log('You ran ' + miles + ' miles, in ' + minutes + ' minutes');

pace = minutes * (1 / miles);

console.log('Your pace was ' + pace + ' minutes per mile');
```

---

*This answer was updated 14/05/21 to remove earlier parts of the post which referred to speed and not pace.*

Comment: Thanks, but that is speed...not pace.

Comment: What do you mean by pace? I might be able to edit the answer.

Comment: Pace is how much time to cover a distance.  For example, running an 8-minute mile.  It takes 8 minutes to run 1 mile.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope it's more helpful this time?

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert seconds to minutes

```
const minutes = seconds/60;
```

and convert meters to miles

```
const miles = meters / 1609;
```

and simply divide it

```
const milPerMin = miles / minutes;
```

Comment: I understand the first equation.  But the second is incorrect??

1 meter / 1.609 = .62 miles??  A meter doesn't equal over half a mile.

Comment: My bad, its meters / 1609;

Comment: Ah...thanks makes sense.

So, using the data I have presented.  That gives me 1253s to cover 1.09 miles.  Converting the 1253s to minutes and seconds is 20m 53s.  How do I "reduce" from 1.09 miles to 1.0 miles?